# CMS hippo property reading from .yaml file

Tags: hippocms

I need to read the properties which are stated in my one of the `.yaml` file(eg `banner.yaml`). These properties should be read in a java class so that they can be accessed and the operation can be performed wisely.

1. This is my `label.yaml` file

   ```
   /content/documents/administration/labels:
   jcr:primaryType: hippostd:folder
   jcr:mixinTypes: ['mix:referenceable']
   jcr:uuid: 7ec0e757-373b-465a-9886-d072bb813f58
   hippostd:foldertype: [new-resource-bundle, new-untranslated-folder]
   /global:
   jcr:primaryType: hippo:handle
   jcr:mixinTypes: ['hippo:named', 'mix:referenceable']
   jcr:uuid: 31e4796a-4025-48a5-9a6e-c31ba1fb387e
   hippo:name: Global
   ```

How should I access the `hippo:name` property which should return me `Global` as value in one of the java class ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class which extends BaseHstComponent, which allows you to make use of HST Content Bean's

Create a session Object, for this you need to have valid  credentials of your repository.

`Session session = repository.login("admin", "admin".toCharArray());`

Now, create object of javax.jcr.Node, for this you require relPath to your .yaml file.
In your case it will be `/content/documents/administration/labels/global`

`Node node = session.getRootNode().getNode("content/articles/myarticle");`

Now, by using getProperty method you can access the property.

`node.getProperty("hippotranslation:locale");`

you can refere the link https://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/content-repository/jcr-interface.html

Comment: That's a good way of getting properties on a low level. My answer focuses on that it is a resource bundle file. Your answer is more generic. Though I would encourage to use higher level abstractions if possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can't read a yaml file from within the application. The yaml file is bootstrapped in the repository. The data you show represents a resource bundle. You can access it programmatically using the utility class ResourceBundleUtils#getBundle

Or on a template use . Then you can use keys as normal.

I strongly suggest you follow our tutorials before continuing.

more details here:
https://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/translations/hst-2-dynamic-resource-bundles-support.html

Comment: Thanks folk, is there any way to create a global property file( key value pair) which can be read or accessed  in both .FTL and Java class ?

Comment: Follow the link I posted. These bundles are accessible in templates and code.

Comment: Thanks for the help will try this